# Using python to execute adb commands

Tags: python, android, adb

I am learning how to execute adb commands using python And I noticed that to execute adb command
we can use cmd : **Adb.cmd("shell","ls")**
it's clear that the result will be : adb shell ls 
But I want to understand the use of "cmd". Can someone explain that to me . thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cmd` is a method of the `Adb` Python class, which allows you to execute commands on the previously selected device.